# How can I write Fibonacci with for...of?

Tags: javascript

** How can I write a program that produce Fibonacci with for...of in javascript**

I've tried this, and it works well

```
function createFibonacci(number) {
    var i;
    var fib = []; // Initialize array!

    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
      // Next fibonacci number = previous + one before previous
      // Translated to JavaScript:
      fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
      console.log(fib[i]);
    }
}

createFibonacci(8);
```

But I'm wondering if it is possible to write it with **for..of**, is there any way to do this?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to *write* `createFibonacci` with a `for-of` loop, but it would make sense to *consume* a sequence of fibonacci numbers with a `for-of` loop (for instance, from a generator), provided the sequence is limited (or you don't mind looping forever). Are you asking how to *create* the function with `for-of`, or create a function you can *use* via `for-of`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option, using a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):

```js
function createFibonacci(number) {
  // fibonacci generator
  const gen = (function *(i) {
    let a = 1, b = 1, c;
    if (i--) yield a;
    if (i--) yield b;
    while (i--) {
      yield c = a + b;
      [a, b] = [b, c];
    }
  });

  for (let f of gen(number)) {
    console.log(f);
  }
}

createFibonacci(8);
```

As [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154843/how-can-i-write-fibonacci-with-for-of/56155101#comment98938925_56154843) mentioned, the `for...of` loop is just used to consume the sequence, the sequence is actually produced by the generator.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a generator.

```js
function* createFibonacci(number, a = 0, b = 1) {
    if (a === 0)
        if (number--) yield 1;
        else return;
    if (!number--) return
    yield a + b;
    yield* createFibonacci(number, b, a + b);
}

console.log(...createFibonacci(0));
console.log(...createFibonacci(1));
console.log(...createFibonacci(2));
console.log(...createFibonacci(3));
console.log(...createFibonacci(4));
console.log(...createFibonacci(5));
console.log(...createFibonacci(6));
console.log(...createFibonacci(7));
console.log(...createFibonacci(8));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A different approach with a little help from [Rup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243245/rup).

```js
function* createFibonacci(number, index = 1) {
    createFibonacci.values = createFibonacci.values || [0, 1];
    for (; index < createFibonacci.values.length && index < number + 1; ++index)
        yield createFibonacci.values[index];
    if (index >= number + 1) return;
    yield createFibonacci.values[index] = createFibonacci.values[index - 2] + createFibonacci.values[index - 1];
    yield* createFibonacci(number, index + 1);
}

console.log(...createFibonacci(0));
console.log(...createFibonacci(1));
console.log(...createFibonacci(2));
console.log(...createFibonacci(3));
console.log(...createFibonacci(4));
console.log(...createFibonacci(5));
console.log(...createFibonacci(6));
console.log(...createFibonacci(7));
console.log(...createFibonacci(8));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Fibonaci is like 1,1,2,3,5 your code generates 1,2,3,5,...

Comment: @Rup, should i take it?

Comment: Don't mind, up to you. This is a good solution too.